# QWebView with googlemaps don't work

Tags: c++, qt, qwebview, qwebkit

I am work with QT version 4.7.3 in the app in the company , inside in there are a tab for view googlemaps, until last days was working normally but now don't open the page.Here we use proxy for access extern

I try discovered if change API google maps with URL change ||
I do a simple app web in Qt same version for test but don't work URL[white page] ||
I do another browser in QT 5.4 and work it , but now we don't change all application for QT 5.4 , is extensive work .

There are some mode for work URL google maps in Qt 4.7 without change for 5.4 ?
lastways until we have time for implement a change for 5.4 in the company

if somebody can help pls ?

exemple link format URL
http://maps.google.com?ie=UTF8&q=-35.8642,-79.4972&spn=0.005706,0.011362&t=h&z=17&output=classic\"/>

Comment: new to qt here . when I put the url on browser it says over zoom? is that okay?

Comment: I 'm working Linux Ubuntu 64 bits

Comment: yes a little time . i change some number link coordinates it has relations with the company but   is the remainder unalterable

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem lately when working with qt 4.7. I should add I ended using *the Google Maps JavaScript API v3* in my own html page.

I cant find my reference anymore but I saw in a forum that you can lock the version you're using of the javascript when linking with the API.

in the following, you can add v=3 the url

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?**v=3**&key=API_KEY

it was enough to make it work. you can also add **sensor=true** in case.